# Why is mymonero.com blocked when using the Tor Browser?

Tags: mymonero, tor

When trying to access mymonero.com via the Tor Browser I am redirected to another site that says blocked.mymonero.com. When one of the main purposes of monero is to establish anonymity, why is access to mymonero.com being blocked? I recognize that one could use a VPN, but Tor and a VPN should not be mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

According to site operator [fluffyponyza](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5pdnx0/cant_access_mymonerocom_on_tor/dcqen5y/?utm_content=permalink&utm_medium=front&utm_source=reddit&utm_name=Monero) there should be an error message that explains this:

> The site you are visiting is NOT the real MyMonero! Please make sure that in future you type mymonero.com into your address bar, and don't click on links to visit the site. Note that you may also see this message when trying to access MyMonero on Tor, as impersonator sites try and use Tor to reverse-proxy to MyMonero.

Eventually Mymonero will offer 2 solutions that will work with tor:

1. An onion site
2. A downloadable [client](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5pagfp/wip_mymonero_design_by_matt_d_smith/) based on [MyMonero code](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5pagfp/wip_mymonero_design_by_matt_d_smith/)

Until then the error is provided for your protection against [hackers](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5pdnx0/cant_access_mymonerocom_on_tor/dcqen5y/?utm_content=permalink&utm_medium=front&utm_source=reddit&utm_name=Monero):

> that use attacks like POODLE. That's not even counting things like sslstrip + a lock favicon, or URI Unicode hacks, or a sophisticated attacker leveraging a compromised or malleable CA. TLS over Tor is safe only if you verify the fingerprint, or use something that secures it such as DANE (which is largely unsupported and hardly deployed).

Comment: I tried mymonero.com and the ssl representation of  'https://mymonero.com' and both went to https://blocked.mymonero.com/ so it appears something is hard coded at mymonero.com to block Tor access.

Comment: @hidden Yes, same here.  I'm http redirected to blocked.mymonero.com  *without using tor* from all browsers.  I believe it is a CloudFlare issue.  I do use Tor browser occasionally, but not for that website.  I also run a public bitcoin node over Tor. So it seems this might put one's IP address on a blacklist.